# Location of Web and Api middleware group in the project

Tags: laravel

While reading the `Laravel 5.6` docs I found these lines:

> The web.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places
>   in the web middleware group

and

> The api.php file contains routes that the RouteServiceProvider places
>   in the api middleware group

I dont see these groups in the `Middleware directory`.

where can I find the `Web Middlware group` and `Api Middleware group` in the project directory ?

Comment: Are you looking for this [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `$middlewareGroups` property in `app/Http/Kernel.php`